# How do I know what time it is?

Tags: the-witcher-2

There are various events in the Witcher 2 which requires me to drop by a location by, say, 21:00hr.

How do I know what it is now in the game? There's an icon next to the radar, but it doesn't give the exact time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only see the exact time when you're meditating. Just press `Ctrl` and click in the middle of the radial menu to meditate. In the following menu click again on meditate and you'll get a display that shows you the time. Here you can also wait until a specific time, which is very useful if you need to be somewhere at a specific time.

[image]

You can see a rough estimate of the time in your top right corner of the screen. The small circle is actually a clock, you can see the small mark on the outside of the circle indicating the time. In this screenshot it is somewhere around 10 o'clock.

[image]

Comment: I think the icon showing the relative time is also available on the HUD.

Comment: @Raven You're correct, I added that to the answer